# Conditional calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

friends:
  I'm now have a problem about conditional calculation in SQL Server.
  I have set some data from SQL Server as an example in excel like this:

```
No    Employee  Month   Commission1 Commission2
1     A         Jan        10          5
2     A         Jan        10          4
3     B         Jan        15          3
4     B         Jan        15          4
5     C         Jan        10          3
6     C         Jan        10          4
7     D         Jan        13          3
8     D         Jan        13          4
9     DM        Jan        0           6
10    DM        Jan        0           8
11    A         Feb        15          4
12    A         Feb        15          5
13    B         Feb        20          5
14    B         Feb        20          4
15    C         Feb        9           3
16    C         Feb        9           4
17    D         Feb        14          5
18    D         Feb        14          6
19    DM        Feb        0           13
20    DM        Feb        0           10
```

And the result I want is like this:

```
Employee    Jan             No#     Feb             No#  
A           20              2       30              2  
B           30              2       40              2  
C           20              2       18              2  
D           26              2       28              2  
DM          44              10      59              10
```

For every sales,Employee A,B,C,D only have commission1 as payment,the commission2 is for DM. So , in Jan , DM's commission is SUM(E2:E9)

I can do it easy in excel , but how can I do this in sql server?

I make my try code like this:

```
select [Month],Employee,SUM(Commission1) Commission,count(distinct([No]))     No#
from table1
WHERE Employee IN ('A','B','C','D')
group by [Month],Employee
union
select 'DM' as Employee,[Month],SUM(Commission2)     Commission,count(distinct([No])) No#
from table1
WHERE Employee IN ('A','B','C','D','DM')
group by [Month],Employee
```

And I get the result

```
Employee    Month   Commission  No#
A           Jan      20         2
B           Jan      30         2
C           Jan      20         2
D           Jan      26         2
DM          Jan      44         10
A           Feb      30         2
B           Feb      40         2
C           Feb      18         2
D           Feb      28         2
DM          Feb      59         10
```

The result format is not what I want.I tried pivot after this query,but failed,it seems I only can pivot one state?

Another question: If I want the month growth automatic (In actual data , there's not only Jan and Feb) in the  result ,not write [Jan],[Feb],[Mar]... in pivot code, how to do it?

Who can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Posting pictures of data makes it really hard to create testdata in order to solve your problem. Can't use cut and paste

Comment: @t-clausen.dk is this OK? I'm very sorry for that I don't know how to organize my page... and how to give a good format data.

Comment: I edited the format of your question and removed the redundant pictures. You should also include your attempt to solve it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will add my attempt later,Please help!

Comment: You need to add the attempt *when you post the question*, not after..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) solution:

Test data:

```
DECLARE @t table(Employee varchar(2), Month char(3), Commission1 int, Commission2 int)
INSERT @t values
('A','Jan',10,5 ),('A','Jan',10,4),('B','Jan',15,3),
('B','Jan',15,4 ),('C','Jan',10,3),('C','Jan',10,4),
('D','Jan',13,3 ),('D','Jan',13,4),('DM','Jan',0,6),
('DM','Jan',0,8 ),('A','Feb',15,4),('A','Feb',15,5),
('B','Feb',20,5 ),('B','Feb',20,4),('C','Feb',9,3),
('C','Feb',9,4  ),('D','Feb',14,5),('D','Feb',14,6),
('DM','Feb',0,13),('DM','Feb',0,10)
```

Query:

```
;WITH CTE as
( 
 SELECT
   Employee, Month, 
   CASE WHEN Employee = 'DM' THEN
   SUM(Commission2) over (partition by [Month])
   ELSE Commission1 END com,
   CASE WHEN Employee = 'DM' 
   THEN row_number() over
      (PARTITION BY Employee, [Month] ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) ELSE 1 END rn
 FROM @t
) 
SELECT Employee, [Jan], [Feb], [Mar] -- add more months
FROM  
CTE
PIVOT 
(SUM(com) 
 FOR [Month] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar])) AS pvt -- add more months
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Result:

```
Employee    Jan Feb Mar
A           20  30  NULL
B           30  40  NULL
C           20  18  NULL
D           26  28  NULL
DM          44  59  NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I changed some requests,how should I do with pivot 2 columns?

Comment: That is a huge change, you should not change the requirements of the question after posting it, that makes all the answers invalid

Comment: OK , get it ! I would not do that again ! But can you help me again for this question?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In SqlServer you can do so using PIVOT operator as like below:
Please refer [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) syntax

```
select tmp.employee,pv.[jan] as Jan_Commission, pv.[feb] as Feb_Commission from 

(
select employee,month,commission1 from table_name

)tmp
pivot (
sum(commission1)  
for [month] in ([jan],[feb])

)pv;
```

Comment: Downvoter pls mention the reason, so that we will correct the code